# AWS + MongoDB : How to connect to mongo server on AWS linux instance?

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, flask-mongoengine

I launched an AWS linux instance and installed and ran mongo as instructed [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/). The mongo service is running and accepting connections on 27017. However, when I go to the server publik dns with port 27017 the server does not respond and I don't see the default mongo message.

I am trying to run a Python(Flask) server on another instance and trying to connect to the mongo server using the private ip, but the connection does not happen. I get this error message on the terminal :

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: xxx.xx.xx.xx:27017: [Errno
>   111] Connection refused

Is this not the right way to use mongo db on aws ? If this approach is feasible, what is causing the connection to not happen ?

All inputs appreciated, much thanks!

Comment: did you change your security group to allow inbound traffic on port 27017 ? you can make a rule to allow only from the IP of the other server for your testing

Comment: What happens when you connect directly from your AWS instance where MongoDB is running? If this works, then most likely the port is not open: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: @FrédéricHen : It's open to the world

Comment: @Ashafix : I can connect through the terminal. It says accepting connections on port 27017

Comment: This looks like an AWS instance configuration problem. Is port 27017 open in the security settings?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your mongodb is configured to only accept connection from local host. Edit `/etc/mongod.conf` file to comment out the line that bindIP like in the example below -

> ```
> # network interfaces
> net:
>   port: 27017
> #  bindIp: 127.0.0.1 # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
> ```